Constructing a quad sphere with equal edge lengths within edge loops
In computer graphics, a quad sphere is a skew polyhedron which has the same topology as a cube with arbitrarily subdivided sides and every vertex having the same distance from the quad sphere's center. A side-view might look like this:

On the Blender stackexchange, someone asked how to construct this body such that all edges within any given edge loop have the same length. For the purpose of this question, an edge loop is a set of edges each edge of which can be reached through pairs of connected edges which do not share a face.

Interested, but unsure whether this is even mathematically possible, I tried to do it. However, there remain errors which aren't easy to pin down. They are surprisingly subtle, but probably indicate that at least one wrong assumption was made. Specifically, assuming that the circle segments that build the grid of quads on each of the 6 "sides" each have all their vertices within a plane.
Can it be constructed? If so, how?
